# CHECK value is not present in another column in the same table

Tags: sql, sqlite, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I have a table `aliases` which maps 8-char IDs to some other canonical 8-char ID. I want the database engine to make sure there are no loops. Using SQLAlchemy, the table description is (slightly simplified):

```
Table('aliases', database,
    Column('from', CHAR(8), primary_key = True),
    Column('to', CHAR(8), nullable = False),
    CheckConstraint('"to" not in (select "from" from aliases)')
)
```

Which generates the following SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE aliases (
    "from" CHAR(8) NOT NULL, 
    "to" CHAR(8) NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY ("from"), 
    CHECK ("to" not in (select "from" from aliases))
)
```

SQLite chokes with `no such table: aliases`, which makes sense seeing how `aliases` don't exist yet. Is there a way for SQLite (and by extension, any DB engine) to do this kind of check?

Comment: A check constraint cannot contain a subquery (http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html) so you cannot do what you want to do.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff: Oh well... wouldn't you prefer to put that in an answer to be accepted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A check constraint cannot contain a subquery (sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html).

This is generally true in databases that support check constraints.

One way around it is to create a user-defined function that checks in the table.  This is a bit painful in SQLite, because you cannot define the function in SQL.

Another approach is the use of a trigger when you insert or update a value.  The trigger *can* use a subquery to achieve your goal.

Comment: Note that it is considered bad from to use a function that depends on another table in a CHECK constraint.  A trigger is the proper solution.